# Web Analytic web site

Tags: analytics, ecommerce, traffic, visitors, monitoring

I am a student at e-commerce major.I want to analysis my project competitor site for business plan.I need to know number of visitor per day or month but I can't find this analytic.
I used Alexa but it didn't have this feature( I remember Alexa last year shows this analytic but in new version they don't show Number of visitor)
I google it but in all same website.all of theme need to put some code in website.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions regarding [web sites out of your control](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are considered off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to track your competitor site information you can use : http://www.statscrop.com this site will give few important information.

1.Daily Visitors Country Map Analysis.

2.Alexa Traffic Graph Analysis (7days,1month,3month,..and 4 year)

2.Socials Analysis

3.Website Metas Analysis

4.Website Important Html Tags Analysis

5.Indexed Pages Analysis

6.Google Pagerank Analysis

7.W3C HTML Validation Analysis

8.Backward Links Analysis

9.Alexa Traffic Analysis

10.Site Title,Web Age,Alexa Rank,Load Time,Pagerank,SEO Score,Primary Traffic etc...